# undefined reference to 'check_nan'

Tags: c, gcc, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to compile the file (`glove.c` from Stanford NLP https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/src/glove.c) but I'm getting an undefined reference error.

```
aerin@capa:~/Desktop/GloVe/src$ gcc -pthread  glove.c -o glove.out -lm

/tmp/ccZMsGyg.o: In function `glove_thread':
glove.c:(.text+0x9d7): undefined reference to `check_nan'
glove.c:(.text+0xa6a): undefined reference to `check_nan'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't find the answer about "check_nan" on google.  What flag should I use to compile this file? Any tip will greatly help!

Comment: Are you interested in building the entire project or simply trying to compile `glove.c` to object code?

Comment: @yano Thanks for replying. Simply compile the glove.c code!

Comment: `check_nan` is a local function with the `inline` specifier.  Try removing `inline`.

Comment: @yano I've fixed other undefined errors by adding "-pthread" and "-lm" flags.

Comment: @dbush how do I remove inline? (Sorry C newbie here!)

Comment: in that case you don't need to invoke the linker at all, try something like `gcc -c glove.c -o glove.out`, although typically your object files end in `.o`. `-c` option says don't run the linker, so it won't try to find/link the `check_nan` function. Also no need link in the math library.

Comment: @Aaron Remove the keyword `inline` from the source line where `check_nan` is defined.

Comment: @yano This solved the issue! Please add it on the answer. I'll select it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aaron What yano suggested doesn't actually give you a runnable program.  It just gives you an object file that you still need to link later.

Comment: @dbush Yes, I just found out that...

Comment: @dbush but I aslo don't think I can remove "check_nan" part because I have to check nan.

Comment: @Aaron I didn't say to remove the function.  Just to remove the `inline` specifier from the definition.

Comment: @Aaron Also, what version of gcc are you using?  It compiled fine for me with no changes.

Comment: @dbush gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609.

Comment: @Aaron Well, that's why I asked my first question. Simply compiling `glove.c` (what you said you wanted to do) will produce executable code, but not runnable code. If you want to build the entire executable project, you're welcome to go through and compile each source file individually, then link them all together with the appropriate libraries (`check_nan` is in the math library?), but that will take forever and be error prone. Use the project makefile instead.

Comment: @dbush can you let me know the gcc version that you are using?

Comment: @yano still thanks for the help!!

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings;  I compiled it with: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11  -ggdb -c "glove.c"`  This had no problems with the 'inline' function: `check_nan()`.  However, the compiler output 16 messages about implicit conversions.  Warnings should be fixed, not ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the makefile for the full project, you'll see that some options are being passed that you aren't including:

```
CFLAGS = -lm -pthread -Ofast -march=native -funroll-loops -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
...
glove : $(SRCDIR)/glove.c
    $(CC) $(SRCDIR)/glove.c -o $(BUILDDIR)/glove $(CFLAGS)
```

The flag in pariticular you're missing is `-Ofast`.  Add that and it should compile fine.

Alternately, just run `make` from the top level directory to build everything.